# PHP framework to use on GoDaddy host with no shell access

Tags: web-hosting, php, ruby-on-rails

I'm a Ruby-on-Rails developer but am trying to develop a site to run on a GoDaddy Economy hosting account.  This means I don't have Ruby and Rails available so I've decided to go with PHP 5 since the economy hosting *does* provide that.  So to ease development I want a PHP framework (ideally Rails-like like, say, Akelos) that I can install and configure on my GoDaddy site *without having shell access to the hosting server*.

Does anybody have any recommendations or experience with similar?

Comment: Have you reviewed webhostingpad hosting service. In my point of view it is cheaper and supports Ruby-on-Rails.

Comment: No I haven't.  If I was currently in the market for moving to a new hosting service though, I'd be looking at one with Rails expertise, like railsplayground.com or hostingrails.com.

Answer (score 2):

[CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) is similar to RoR, but the `bake` utility is a console app. You could bake your code locally and upload it to your GoDaddy account though. However, you'll have to do all of your unit testing via the browser or do it locally if you want to test via the CLI. It's a bit less convenient, but that's the cost of choosing an economy hosting package.

Comment: We use Cake on over 50 of our clients' sites and never have shell access.  We do web-based unit testing and barely touch the console.  Works great.  :-)

Comment: CakePHP is also one of the most 'Rails-like' PHP frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Rails developer, your best choice would be to develop a Rails application. There are awesome web hosts out there like Site5 which will be happy to assist you with whatever Rails issues you have. You can check [this](http://www.site5.com/hosting/web/#programming_languages) page.

Also, they let you use SSH if you are still up for PHP.

To answer your question directly - use Yii framework. It has its own GUI and if you can code in PHP, you'll love it. I promise.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to use Rails but I'm already locked into the  GoDaddy account and funds are tight!

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). It's a good framework, but not very like Rails. Otherwise, it don't need shell access.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony is rails like (I believe it's essentially of php port of rails) and although I've not used GoDaddy for hosting before it seems others have had success hosting it there. http://gfaraj.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/deploying-a-symfony-project-on-godaddy-shared-hosting/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CodeIgniter, a PHP framework. No shell access required. It isn't as strict as RoR as far as I know and the documentation and community are excellent.